# Merging two WAV files with Java only plays the last part

Tags: java, audio

I'm trying to write an Application to record a sound on Android and send it through TCP to a Server running on a PC. My main Problem is to buffer received bytes and collect them all on a single file.

I can see by Debugging my code that the frameLength grows currectly by reading the old content and appending the new ones, but the File size on Disk remains constant and MediaPlayer plays only the last recorded part.

```
private static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;
private File waveFile;

private void toWaveFile(final byte[] soundBytes) throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException {
    final InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(soundBytes);

    final AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(SAMPLE_RATE, 16, 1, true, false);
    final AudioInputStream newAudioInputStream = new AudioInputStream(inputStream, format, soundBytes.length);

    if (waveFile == null) {
        waveFile = new File(Config.getInstance().readSetting("tempFolder.path") + "/test_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".wav");

        AudioSystem.write(newAudioInputStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, waveFile);
    } else {
        final AudioInputStream currentContentInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(waveFile);
        final AudioInputStream appendedFilesAudioInputStream = new AudioInputStream(
                new SequenceInputStream(currentContentInputStream, newAudioInputStream),
                currentContentInputStream.getFormat(),
                currentContentInputStream.getFrameLength() + newAudioInputStream.getFrameLength());

        AudioSystem.write(appendedFilesAudioInputStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, waveFile);
    }
}
```

Any Help is hightly appreciated